# Smalltalk (Pharo) methods

Tags: methods, smalltalk

I am trying to learn Smalltalk (Pharo), but since not so many documentaion available I would like to ask for some help. 
I have There two classes, CarRental and Car, and a Test class, CarRentalTest. 
Now, supporse rental service has a fixednuber of cars.

```
| carRental |
carRental := CarRental new.
carRental
    addCar: Car panda;
    addCar: Car panda;
    addCar: Car tesla.
self assert: carRental totalCars size = 3
```

However, my addCar method is red, how can I fix it?

Comment: Do you mean the method name "addCar:" is red in the method you quoted? If I am not mistaken, that would indicate that there is no such method in any class. Therefore, please also post the definition of that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method `addCar:` is red (note the colon at the end) because you haven't defined it.  Let's write it down then:

The class `CarRental` must have an instance variable which will hold all its cars. Let's say we name it `cars`.

In the `initialize` method (instance side) we need to do the following

```
CarRental >> initialize
  super initialize.
  cars := OrderedCollection new.
```

Now, if we create a new instance of `CarRental` it will have an empty `OrderedCollection` in its `cars` ivar.

Now we can add the `addCar:` method like this

```
CarRental >> addCar: aCar
  cars add: aCar
```

Finally, make sure that you have something like this

```
CarRental >> totalCars
  ^cars size
```

Review your code and keep trying!

Comment: thank you very much for the detailed explanation! It is very helpful!

Answer (score 3):

there is a lot of documentation available for pharo:

here some hints:

- http://books.pharo.org (I'd recommend start with "Pharo by Example")
- http://mooc.pharo.org
- this excellent list: [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0xF4fnGaE2w&list=PLqbtQ7OkSta0ULYAd7Qdxof851ybh-*m*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0xF4fnGaE2w&list=PLqbtQ7OkSta0ULYAd7Qdxof851ybh-_m_) (based on an old version of Pharo, but everything applies).

Now, about your question, is hard to have an answer, it depends on a lot of things for example: is the container a Set or an OrderedCollection? `Car panda` answers what? a new instance of Car or always the same?

Comment: Thanks for the resources, I am using these books/tutorials, but it is a bif confusing when you look for the pure oop